# Is the detox-cli a compiler or an interpreter

Tags: android, ios, react-native, automated-tests, detox

I am referring to the [detox-cli](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/guide/uninstalling/#detox-cli) used in the [Detox](https://wix.github.io/Detox/) test framework for react native devices.

I will like to know if the detox-cli is a compiler or an interpreter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

detox-cli is a command-line tool for running automated tests on JavaScript code. It is not a compiler or interpreter. It is designed to simplify the process of running tests on different environments and configurations by providing a single command to run all tests. It is commonly used to run tests for React Native and React projects